# Simple Linux tool for timing an http request in milliseconds

Tags: linux, http, timing

I'm looking for a simple tool or built-in command that will allow me to measure with millisecond accuracy the time it takes to fetch a remote web page from a given URL.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Does this do what you're looking for?

```
time wget http://example.com
```

Comment: This will include the time it takes to start and run wget, which can be significantly longer than the server's response time.

Comment: @PaulLynch: I did a simple test. I ran this in one terminal: `rm foo; touch foo; python -m SimpleHTTPServer` and in another: `time wget --quiet --output-document=/dev/null localhost:8000/foo` and the result was 2 milliseconds. I ran the same `wget` against google.com (which retrieves about 10K characters) and got about a quarter of a second. So let's call the start/run time about 1% in that case. Then, for comparison, I did `time curl file://foo` and got about 4 milliseconds.

Comment: It seems you are right, for http requests-- for which I get only about 2ms of slowdown.  I was trying to get an https URL.  For that, wget is about 25ms slower for a request Chrome returns in about 10ms (and not "from cache").  Both wget and Chrome are running on the same machine as the webserver, and are addressing it as "localhost", so I blame wget for the time difference.

Answer (score 7):

[Httping](http://www.vanheusden.com/httping/) will do that.

> Httping is like 'ping' but for http-requests.
>   Give it an url, and it'll show you how long it takes to connect, send a request and retrieve the reply (only the headers). Be aware that the transmission across the network also takes time! So it measures the latency of the webserver + network.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with curl as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22625150/338265)

Create a new file, `curl-format.txt`, and paste in:

```
    time_namelookup:  %{time_namelookup}\n
       time_connect:  %{time_connect}\n
    time_appconnect:  %{time_appconnect}\n
   time_pretransfer:  %{time_pretransfer}\n
      time_redirect:  %{time_redirect}\n
 time_starttransfer:  %{time_starttransfer}\n
                    ----------\n
         time_total:  %{time_total}\n
```

Then run curl like this:

`curl -w "@curl-format.txt" -o /dev/null -s "http://wordpress.com/"`

Answer (score 3):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) will let you examine a transfer in a lot of detail.  You can see how long it takes to download a single file, as Dennis suggested, or if you open the URL in a web browser, you can see how long it takes to load all of the related files (images, scripts, etc).